# QR algorithm for General Eigenvalue Problems

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I have an eigenvalue problem of the following form:-$$Ax-\lambda Bx=0 $$ I was wondering if I can apply QR without inverting B to find $\lambda $. I read that jacobi-davidson and QZ can handle this but can QR do it? A and B may or may not be symmetric but are definitely real.

Answer (score 1):

No. The QZ algorithm is to the generalized eigenvalue problem what the QR algorithm is the standard eigenvalue problem. The QZ algorithm reduces $A$ to quasi-triangular form $S = Q^TAZ$ and $B$ to triangular form $T = Q^TAZ$. The matrices $Q$ and $Z$ are orthonormal matrices, hence the reduction process is very stable. Moreover, $Ax = \lambda Bx$ if and only if $Sy = \lambda T y$, where $y = Z^Tx$. The eigenvalues of $(A,B)$ can be read off from the diagonal blocks of $(S,T)$.